# How do I uninstall Drush?

Tags: drush, composer

There is a method of [installing Drush via Composer](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#installupdate---composer).

```bash
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

How do I uninstall it using Composer?

Comment: Not really Drupal-related as such but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217477/remove-something-from-composer-global

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that. Drush has the documentation how to install it, therefore I think there should be drush related information how to uninstall it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems there is no single remove command, so you need to:

1. Edit your `composer.json` file, e.g.

   ```
   vim ~/.composer/composer.json
   ```

   and remove line containing drush. Save the file.
2. Update Composer PHP packages by:

   ```
   composer global update
   ```

   It will remove a globally installed `drush`.

If you don't have `composer` command in your PATH, try `php composer.phar` instead.

See: [How to remove a package from composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217477/how-to-remove-a-package-from-composer).

Comment: There is no mention of `drush` in my `~/.composer/composer.json`. Even I run `composer global update` it is not removing. I can still see it using `drush version` command. Why is so? I have PHP 5.3.29 on Ubuntu 14.04. Please advise.

Comment: @NiladriSarkar Maybe drush has been installed by the different method. Check `which drush` or check to [which package](http://superuser.com/q/10997/87805) this file belong, etc.

Comment: `which drush` shows `/usr/local/bin/drush`. And I installed drush using `composer`. Reference: http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ and http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install-alternative/. How can I resolve it now please help!

Comment: @NiladriSarkar It may be just a symlink, so check where it points to, or just remove the symlink. It's best if you ask another question saying your drush is not in `composer.json` and it's still there, but it's rather question at superuser. Since it won't be a quick one. Or you may add bounty to this one clarifying how this doesn't solve the problem for you. Normally it should be removed by `composer global update` if global `composer.js` doesn't have it.

Comment: I have followed your instructions, now my composer.json only contains {}. composer does not want to remove drush nor does it want to reinstall it or install a different version. Stupid me hasn't made a backup of the file :( Would love to hear how to get out of this mess...

Answer (score 16):

You can use `composer global remove drush/drush` to uninstall a global Drush.

Or use `composer remove drush/drush` to uninstall a project-local Drush.