# After installing Drush on Mac it only downloads drupal 6x

Tags: drush

I am having issues installing Drush on Mac OSX 10.9.5. I have tried a variety of methods. The most successful have been;

[Using homebrew](https://www.drupal.org/node/954766)

[Drush 7 using composer](http://whaaat.com/installing-drush-7-using-composer)

Each method had produced a version of Drush, however each appears old and `drush dl drupal` downloads the 6.x version, as does `drush dl drupal 7.x`.

Can you please suggest:

1) How to ensure old versions of drush are removed to ensure that a new installation goes smoothly.

2) The recommended method for installing the latest stable Drush version on Mac OSX 10.9.5

I had tried to delete the old drush version manually by removing folders. Now the composer installation method seems to fail as I get:

```
Pauls-iMac:~ Trotter$ composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
Changed current directory to /Users/Trotter/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing drush/drush (dev-master 78b1538)
    Cloning 78b15385ba97890dc3431790494f26d6be99ede9
    Failed to download drush/drush from source: The process "git clone --no-checkout 'git://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git' '/Users/Trotter/.composer/vendor/drush/drush' && cd '/Users/Trotter/.composer/vendor/drush/drush' && git remote add composer 'git://github.com/drush-ops/drush.git' && git fetch composer" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing drush/drush (dev-master 78b1538)
    Loading from cache

    Skipped installation of bin drush for package drush/drush: name conflicts with an existing file
    Skipped installation of bin drush.php for package drush/drush: name conflicts with an existing file
    Skipped installation of bin drush.bat for package drush/drush: name conflicts with an existing file
    Skipped installation of bin drush.complete.sh for package drush/drush: name conflicts with an existing file
```

I can see that I don't have drush installed as `what drush` gives `No such file or directory` and `drush info` gives `-bash: drush: command not found`

Comment: Which drush not what drush. Try uninstalling drush via composer.json first http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/135599/how-to-uninstall-drush-via-composer

Comment: Do you have write permission to your ~/.composer directory?

Comment: Actually it looks like the ssh command to github is timing out. I had this issue on Yosemite. You might need to flush the DNS cache. What fixed it in the end for me was a p-ram reset. Reboot with command, option, P and R keys held down until you hear the chime a couple of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drush 7.x doesn't only download Drupal 7 of course. Drush 5 will download Drupal 7 too. Drush 7 is required for Drupal 8 and needs to be selected when installing with `composer global require drush/drush:dev-master`. Ps the recommended method is the composer method. This what I use on OS X 10.9.

Find old versions of drush with `which drush`. Check where they live with`ls -l [path from which drush]`. Rinse and repeat until the only one left is in your home folder inside the hidden composer directory.

Check the version of the installed drush with `drush --version`

Make sure you don't have a `.drushrc` somewhere with a default core version specified.

Comment: Thanks for all of your helpful suggestions Queenvictoria. I tried the RAM set. I  I have managed to remove a 'require dev' dependancy that composer seemed to have (I noticed Updating dependencies (including require-dev) when updating in composer). After doing that I was able to download Drush 6 with composer. This install of Drush was able to download D7 using `drush dl drupal-7.x`

Answer (score 0):

> Skipped installation of bin `drush` for package `drush/drush`: name conflicts with an existing file

Make sure to `unset COMPOSER_BIN_DIR` shell variable before running Composer command as it may conflict with `bin-dir` defined in your `composer.json` file. To check your current value of `bin-dir`, run `composer config bin-dir` (where your Drush may be present).